# ReactJS : Writting a style in createStyle method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs

Through edge developer tools , I have adjusted below style -

[image]

I want `.MuiAccordion-root.Mui-expanded` to be with margin `2px`. By default its `16px`
So I written below style in react where I have used accordion -

```
createStyles({
root : {
"& .MuiAccordion-root.Mui-expanded":{
margin : "2px 0"
}
}
})
```

After setting this, when I refresh my page , I dont see this style has got applied. I again see default style with margin 16px.

How can I write style so that it could take margin 2px ?

Answer (score 1):

Personnally I do it via a `styles.module.scss` file

```js
import styles from './styles.module.scss';

<Accordion className={styles.accordion}>
  <AccordionSummary
    expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
    aria-controls="panel1a-content"
    id="panel1a-header"
  >
    <Typography>Accordion 1</Typography>
  </AccordionSummary>
  <AccordionDetails>
    <Typography>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse
      malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis eget.
    </Typography>
  </AccordionDetails>
</Accordion>
```

```css
.accordion {
  :global(.Mui-expanded) {
    margin: 2px 0;
  }
}
```